# Laravel gmail mail button

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send a mail where the template of the mail will have a button which is similar to the `View issue` button of Gmail (as shown in the image below)

[image]

How can I send a custom template in my mail?

Comment: Your questions needs clarification. Are you trying to send a mail where the template of the mail will have a button which is similar to the `View issue` button of Gmail ?

Comment: Yes. I want button in subject

Comment: Please read [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeune Guerrier : this is not the question !

The question is how to add one click action for gmail... more precisions were appreciated...

In fact you can test markup if sender and receiver is your gmail email. It works. But you need to register here if you want to use it on your production website : https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('email@example.com', 'John Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Then create a blade file `welcome.blade.php` in `resources/views/emails` folder.

`welcome.blade.php` will be the custom template you want to sent, so this is where you will place the css and html for the `View Order` button.